# Get Shibboleth user Attributes in Web Browser Headers

Tags: apache, streamlit, shibboleth

Lately I have been developing a streamlit app and I am using Shibboleth as Auth SSO. I am using Shibboleth v. 3.4.1 and Apache v. 2.4.37. I will try my best to describe the problem I am encountering, bear with me because english is not my first language: **I want to profile all authenticated users. I basically want to take their id and assign each user a specific role** (possibily i would like to do this on streamlit client side), for example: user with a "student" profile can only view specific pages on my streamlit web app.

I have been following Shibboleth configuration guides, I have my
`attribute_map.xml` where i map all the user attributes I want, the Shibboleth configuration file `shibboleth2.xml`, and my application configuration file.

Here are listed all the user attributes at mysite/Shibboleth.sso/Session:

```
Miscellaneous
Session Expiration (barring inactivity): 
Client Address: 
SSO Protocol: 
Identity Provider: 
Authentication Time: 
Authentication Context Class: 
Authentication Context Decl: (none)

Attributes
agency: 
id: 
displayName: 
login_name:
```

This is my config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <mysite>
        ServerAlias <mysite>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule . https://<myurl>%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        #RequestHeader set AJP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_REMOTE_USER %{AJP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_REMOTE_USER}e
        #RequestHeader set AJP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_<AttributeName> %{AJP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_<AttributeName>}e

</VirtualHost>

#<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        #RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
        #RequestHeader set HTTP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_<AttributeName> %{HTTP_SHIB_ATTRIBUTE_<AttributeName>}e
#</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName <mysite>
        DocumentRoot []
        Include []
        ErrorLog []
        CustomLog []
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        RewriteEngine On

       <Location />
               AuthType shibboleth
               ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
               ShibRequestSetting applicationId <mysite>
               ShibUseHeaders Off
               Require valid-user
               ProxyPass ajp://<myip>/ timeout=300
               ProxyPassReverse ajp://<myip>/
       </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**I want to get Shibboleth user Attributes** (actually I need only id) **and display them in the web browser's headers.** I have already tried to set `ShibUseHeaders On` but it's not working and I can't see the authenticated user attributes anywhere on my browser log panel.

I really cannot understand why the user attributes are not showing in browser headers...
Do you have any ideas or suggestion? I would really appreciate some help, I am stuck at this point and I have zero ideas.

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into the same issue.